# Is there ever a good reason to override the usage of children props in React with a complex object?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

React seems to allow you to pass objects via the children prop and I was wondering if there's ever a good reason that you'd want to do so when the alternative of just passing the object as props exists?

ex.

```
type Props = {
  children: {
    a: string;
    b: number;
  }
};

const SomeComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({children}) => {
  return (<><p>{children.a}</p><div>{children.b}</div></>);
}
```

The call for said component would look like

```
<SomeComponent>{{a: "foo", b: 1}}</SomeComponent>
```

Alternative

```
type Props = {
  a: string;
  b: number;
};

const SomeComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({a, b}) => {
  return (<><p>{a}</p><div>{b}</div></>);
}
```

The call for said component would look like (ignore the fact that the props can be explicit in this case and there's no need for object destructuring since the use case is for passing an object)

```
<SomeComponent {...{a: "foo", b: 1}} />
```

Comment: That's really a matter of opinion more than objective React use. One dev's idea of "good use-case" is another's example of "that's insane, never do this".

Comment: Seems opinion-based and broad (please ask about a specific, practical problem) but the second idiom is far more common. The first idiom is usually used to pass JSX objects, not JS data objects.

Comment: @ggorlen I wouldn't call it _opinion-based_, there are principles that you should follow if you want to keep your code clean. And one of them is to leave the `children` keyword as a restricted keyword. It's not an opinion, it's a fact.

Comment: Except it's not because `children` is not a reserved keyword, neither in JS, nor in React linting tools. So as you've just demonstrated this is clearly a question where different devs have different opinions, and will state them as fact. Which is why this kind of question is off topic (and of course sometimes, just a rephrasing can pull it out of opinion territory)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Then we would have to ask the philosophers when does an opinion turn into a principle.

Comment: No, we just need to ask our [list of permitted topics](/help/on-topic) policy article, which exists specifically for this reason.

Comment: @kinduser Regardless of whether it's opinion, it's still off-topic because there's no practical problem OP is facing here, just a "best practice" design speculation. "Is there ever?" is a hard question to answer definitively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there ever a good reason to override the usage of children props in React with a complex object?

tl;dr - **no**.

No, there is no a good reason to *override* `children` property in React. Just like in other libraries/frameworks there are restricted keywords, patterns and principles, so they are in React.

It may not throw any compile errors, however you will simply confuse other developers using your code in the future and you will decrease the readability of your code.